# Project Runnig error Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio, Version=14.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem with my project. When I run it with `ssms 2017` it's working. But when I want to run it with `ssms 2018` I have error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio, Version=14.0.0.0.

```
public class WindowsActivationHandler
{
    public event WindowActivated RegisteredServerActivated;
    public event WindowActivated RegisteredServersDeactivated;
    public event WindowActivated ObjectExplorerActivated;
    public event WindowActivated ObjectExplorerDeactivated;
    public event WindowActivated SqlEditorActivated;
    public event WindowActivated SqlEditorDeactivated;
    public event WindowActivated WindowClosing;


    public WindowsActivationHandler()
    {
        var app = (DTE2)ServiceCache.ExtensibilityModel;
        app.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated += WindowEvents_WindowActivated;
        app.Events.WindowEvents.WindowClosing += WindowEvents_WindowClosing;
    }
}
```

I have error on this line:

```
var app = (DTE2)ServiceCache.ExtensibilityModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because the assembly version of 14.0.0.0 is specifically for SSMS 2017. I think the new reference should be version 15.0.0.0 which is for SSMS 2018.